# Parallel always seems slower while calculating prime

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, primes

This is probably not strange, it's just something I can't really seem to explain. I was just experimenting a little with parallel programming and I thought I'd implement the most straightforward example of something that can be paralleled; calculating prime.

The thing is: I just can't seem to get the 4 logical processors to calculate prime faster than when I do it single threaded. Why is that? (I have an i7-4500u)

Here's my code (you can just paste it in a new console app basically):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();
        p.Start();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        StartMonitoringTask();

        // This puts my cpu at 33%, but is really fast.
        for (long current = 3; current < long.MaxValue; current++)
        {
            DeterminePrimeAndAddToTotal(current);
        }

        // This puts my cpu at 100%, but is way slower.
        Parallel.For(3, long.MaxValue, (current) => DeterminePrimeAndAddToTotal(current));
    }

    private long lastPrime = 0;
    private long totalFound = 0;

    private void DeterminePrimeAndAddToTotal(long primeOrNot)
    {
        bool isPrime = true;

        if (primeOrNot % 2 == 0) return; // even number? never prime.

        long root = (long)Math.Sqrt((long)primeOrNot);
        for (int i = 3; i <= root; i += 2) // check only uneven numbers.
        {
            if (primeOrNot % i == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(isPrime)
        {
            totalFound++;
            lastPrime = primeOrNot;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This just starts a task to monitor the progress.
    /// It's outputs the results to the console every second or so.
    /// </summary>
    private void StartMonitoringTask()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            while (true)
            {
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();

                Console.WriteLine(
                    "found: " + totalFound + 
                    ", last: " + lastPrime + 
                    ", " + (totalFound / (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)) + " p/s");
            }
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
```

UPDATE (based on Frode's answer):
Frode's answer seemed plausible, so to prove it I added besides the for and parallel loop a Parallel.Invoke of a number of actions. Like this:

```
        var numberOfActions = 20;

        var actions = new List<Action>();
        long chunkSize = int.MaxValue / numberOfActions;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfActions; i++)
        {
            long from, to;

            from = i == 0 ? 3 : (i * chunkSize);
            to = (i + 1) * chunkSize;

            actions.Add(new Action(() => { for (long j = from; j < to; j++) DeterminePrimeAndAddToTotal(j); }));
        }

        Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());
```

This seems just as slow as the Parallel.For though. What am I missing?

Comment: How can you tell that it is slower... You have a race condition here, which could easily "lower" the results.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz I either comment the for loop or comment the parallel loop. I have them both uncommented here. Other than that, the conditions for both loops are the same.

Comment: You mean commenting-out... anyway, this is irrelevant to the race condition problem.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz How so? If you run the code, what results do you get?

Comment: I'm working on an answer. until then, you cannot expect a race condition to be deterministic - so... what point would be in answering that?

Answer (score 0):

The cost of spinning new threads for each single integer value in the int64-range is very costly.

Split the int64-range in, say 10 chunks, and execute each for-chunk using Parallel.Invoke(Action[] action) instead.

Then you will most certainly see the performance gain.

```
    Parallel.Invoke(
        ()=> { for(int i=3;i<a;i++) DeterminePrimeAndAddToTotal(i); },
        ()=> { for(int i=a;i<b;i++) DeterminePrimeAndAddToTotal(i); },
        ()=> { for(int i=b;i<c;i++) DeterminePrimeAndAddToTotal(i); },
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore errors in prime detection (2 is a prime, although it's even).

You have two fundamental problems: fallacious bench-marking, and a race condition.

About bench-marking: You must bench-mark in real-life condition (or as closest you can get to that)...
In real-life the code is compiled for "Release" and not "Debug".
In real-life the code is running without debugger attached to it.

And of course, usually, when you bench-mark some code, you don't want to include the JIT times, or other one-time penalties.

As for the race condition, just read [this Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software). There is a perfect example of what happening in your code (two threads trying to increment a value concurrently). Then there are two ways to solve that race condition:

- mutual exclusion: Preventing more than 1 thread to access the variable at a time.
- removing shared variables: Removing the possibility for a race altogether (but not always possible.

I will go with the second solution, because it has less penalties.
To achieve that, I'll use PLINQ.
You can test the code, but you should run it without debugging. The parallel part do run faster (on a weak computer with only 2 cores, it runs twice as fast).

```
private const int ITERATIONS = 1000000;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Test();
        p.Start();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        DeterminePrimeAndAddToTotal(1);

        var primes = Enumerable.Range(2, ITERATIONS)
                               .Select(num => new { Number = num, IsPrime = DeterminePrimeAndAddToTotal(num) })
                               .Where(value => value.IsPrime);

        var parallelPrimes = Enumerable.Range(2, ITERATIONS)
                                       .AsParallel()
                                       .Select(num => new { Number = num, IsPrime = DeterminePrimeAndAddToTotal(num) })
                                       .Where(value => value.IsPrime);

        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        Console.WriteLine(primes.Count());
        watch.Stop();
        var nonParallelTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        Console.WriteLine(parallelPrimes.Count());

        watch.Stop();
        var parallelTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        Console.WriteLine("parallel/non-parallel");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}/{1}", parallelTime, nonParallelTime));
    }

    private bool DeterminePrimeAndAddToTotal(long primeOrNot)
    {
        bool isPrime = primeOrNot <= 2 || (primeOrNot % 2 != 0);

        long root = (long)Math.Sqrt((long)primeOrNot);

        for (int i = 3; i <= root && isPrime; i += 2) // check only uneven numbers.
        {
            if (primeOrNot % i == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
            }
        }

        return isPrime;
    }
```

This is still a shitty bench-mark though... (It's just for testing parallelism, and not for checking any valuable information);

Comment: I start the loop at 3, as you may have noticed. I'm ignoring 1 & 2 for now. Not ignoring 1 & 2 causes an extra (nearly unnecessary) check in the method.

Comment: @GerbenRampaart fine... this is the least important problem here.

Comment: I'm shortly afk. Sry. When I get back I'm going to read your answer carefully. Thx for now.

Comment: I ran Release all the time.

Comment: I dropped the storing of the last found prime and replaced the totalFound++ with Interlocked.Increment(ref totalCount). I don't really see though how the race condition could affect performance so much. I only write the value.

Comment: @GerbenRampaart The race condition does not effect performance (in this case). Rather, it corrupts the value in `totalFound`, and actually makes it smaller.

Comment: @GerbenRampaart and because you do not measure the time it takes to find primes from a predefined range of number, and rather measure how many primes are found in a predefined amount of time - you think that the lower reported `totalFound` is a performance issue.